# Unable to understand recursive function calls

Tags: java, recursion, recursive-backtracking

I'm new to programming and was learning about recursive functions from "Intro to Java Programming ~Liang". While recursive functions fascinate me, I think I'm not able to completely understand how the methods call work internally.

I understand that once the method reaches the base case and executes whatever is mentioned in its logic, it transfers the control to the previous method that called it (which is the same method in recursion).

For understanding it better I developed a sample  program and used debugging to see how the control is jumping from one method call to another. This all looks very interesting that how the calls are made from one method to the same method from within its body.

However, one thing that I'm not able to still understand is why some statements are executed from the base case even when the base case condition is not reached yet.

I'm attaching the code and the images that the recursive method produces

[image]

```
enter code here

package Ch18;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Circle;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class MyRecursiveCircles2 extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        CirclePane2 circlePane = new CirclePane2();
        TextField tfOrder = new TextField();
        tfOrder.setOnAction(e -> circlePane.setCircleCount(Integer.parseInt(tfOrder.getText())));
        tfOrder.setPrefColumnCount(4);
        tfOrder.setAlignment(Pos.BOTTOM_LEFT);

        HBox hbox = new HBox(10);
        hbox.getChildren().addAll(new Label("Enter order: "), tfOrder);
        hbox.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        BorderPane rootPane = new BorderPane();

        StackPane spCircle = new StackPane();
        StackPane spTexts = new StackPane();
        spCircle.setPadding(new Insets(10));
        spCircle.getChildren().add(circlePane);
        spTexts.setPadding(new Insets(10));
        spTexts.getChildren().add(hbox);

        rootPane.setCenter(spCircle);
        rootPane.setBottom(spTexts);

        Scene scene = new Scene(rootPane, 400, 400);
        scene.widthProperty().addListener(ov -> circlePane.createCircle());
        scene.heightProperty().addListener(ov -> circlePane.createCircle());

        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Application.launch(args);
    }
}

class CirclePane2 extends Pane {
    private int count;
    private double radius;

    public CirclePane2() {
        this.count = 0;
    }

    public void setCircleCount(int count) {
        this.count = count;
        createCircle();
    }

    public void createCircle() {
        double xPos = getWidth() / 2;
        double yPos = getHeight() / 2;
        radius = getHeight() / 2;
        getChildren().clear();
        displayCircle(count, xPos, yPos, radius);
    }

    public void displayCircle(int count, double xPos, double yPos, double radius) {
        if (count == 0) {
            Circle circle = new Circle(xPos, yPos, radius);
//          circle.setStroke(Color.BLACK);
            circle.setStroke(null);
            circle.setFill(new Color(0.0, 0.5, 0.0, 0.5));
//          circle.setFill(null);
            this.getChildren().add(circle);
            System.out.println("Hello World"); <-------== WHY??
        } else {
            displayCircle(count - 1, xPos - (radius / 2), yPos, radius - (radius / 2));
            displayCircle(count - 1, xPos + (radius / 2), yPos, radius - (radius / 2));
            displayCircle(count - 1, xPos, yPos - (radius / 2), radius - (radius / 2));
            displayCircle(count - 1, xPos, yPos + (radius / 2), radius - (radius / 2));
//
//          displayCircle(count - 1, xPos - (radius / 2), yPos - (radius / 2), radius - (radius / 2));
//          displayCircle(count - 1, xPos + (radius / 2), yPos + (radius / 2), radius - (radius / 2));
//          displayCircle(count - 1, xPos + (radius / 2), yPos - (radius / 2), radius - (radius / 2));
//          displayCircle(count - 1, xPos - (radius / 2), yPos + (radius / 2), radius - (radius / 2));
        }
    }
}
```

This code also contains some commented code text as I was experimenting with. When I run the above code it works the way I want but it prints Hello World 8 times even before I put any numbers in the space provided. Why is it so?

Comment: in the figure, there's more than 8 "Hello World"s

Comment: Yes that is because I expanded the application window, which changed the width of the window and that executed the createCircle() method as I have added a listener to the width property. But if you run the program without changing any width or height of the program then it prints "hello world" only 8 times. Why is it so?

Comment: add before or after printing hello world, System.out.println(xPos+","+ yPos+","+ radius); so you can figure out what is happening